# What does it mean for a higher glass transition temperature in terms of crystallinity?

Tags: polymers, materials

The glass transition temperature is associated with amorphous regions in a polymer. If I have observed in a lab experiment that polymers with a higher glass transition temperature tend to have less crystalline structures, how should I interpret this?

Comment: Mostly coincidence. It's much more useful to look at and compare specific, comparable examples and explain their actual properties. E.g.  the different Tg's and crystallinities of LDPE and HDPE.

Answer (score 1):

A higher glass transition indicates less energy is required for the bonds of the glass to relax their strain. This is usually due to a slower cooling rate. In a slower cooling rate regime, more time is allowed for crystallization to occur.  So while you are correct to observe a correlation, one does not cause the other but rather they have a common cause of the slower cooling rate.